# Run JavaScript Function ONLY when Submit is Pushed?

Tags: javascript

I currently have a drop-down with all of the options tied to functions, and the below code executing them. Is there anyway to have my code run the function when the submit button is pushed vs. having it run right when the drop-down option is selected?

```
      if(SList[slist][option]) {
        // if option from the last Select, add text-content, else, set dropdown list
        if(slist == 'scontent'){;
var selected = SList[slist][option];
functions[selected]();
}
```

Comment: Create a submit event handler for the form and execute the code there.

Comment: I added this but for some reason it doesn't seem to like to call the function...
    window.addEventListener('submit', functions[selected], true);

Comment: You will likely need to prevent the default behaviour at the beginning of your function to stop it from firing the submit, then manually submit the form at the end of the function.

Comment: Do you have an example of this? Having trouble wrapping my head around this.

Comment: Sorry, I may not have been correct as it looks like it depends on what you return from the function. To explain though, when you run a handler for the event, it will wait until you return either TRUE or FALSE from the function. True will fire the submit, false will not. If you return nothing then it will fire it once the function has finished running. preventDefault() (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault) will stop it from firing without having to return false. 

Also, addEventListner() can be attached to the object that will be firing the event.

Answer (score -1):

in your html use a onsubmit=""

```
<form onsubmit="return yourFunction()">
.......
........
.......
</form>
```

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't seem to be working, check out the demo here: http://hawkgen.com/gen/

Comment: when calling on submit you need to use the return keyword this means that is your function returns true it will allow it to pass and otherwise it fill stop it from going ahead. you can make your function do everything it needs and at the very end return true allowing it to pass